# Erasing the word "eloheinu"?

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names

Can "eloheinu" (written in Hebrew letters) be erased, or is it considered mechikath hashem? I could only find prohibition of erasing "elohim", so I was wondering if this could be similar to writing "God" in English.

Just looking for definitive sources on the matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Still prohibited. The general rule is ([Yesodei HaTorah 6:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=62), [YD 276:9](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6787)) prefixes conjugated to one of God's names are permitted to erase while suffixes are prohibited (without statutory punishment). The root name though is definitely fully prohibited.

So derivatives of א-לוה or א-להים like א-להיך א-להינו א-להי א-להיכם are all prohibited (though you couldn't be punished for erasing the last letters).